# What part do I need to get this small 12V DC pump running?

Tags: power-supply

I am searching for the other half of a 120VAC-to-12VDC power supply, to power a cat water fountain. This is surprisingly hard, I think because I'm not using the correct language. The manufacturer's website shows the pump but does not sell it (item TP-200): http://skyish-zs.com/english/enproduct-1.htm#ENTP200

What exactly am I looking for in electronics terms? Here are pictures of the pump specifications, which has a cable attached to a male 12V jack that is apx 5mm external diameter and just over 2mm internal diameter. I am trying to find the part that is a female jack leading to a 120V AC adapter.

[image: 12VDC pump label]

[image: Male jack side view]

[image: Male jack top view]

Comment: AC-AC transformer or wall wart with 12V output. Get one with a barrel jack connector matching the outer diameter.

Comment: `120VAC-to-12VDC power supply` ... that pump requires 12 V AC, not DC

Comment: Important point that it is 12VAC, not 12VDC, at the pump! So it's an AC-AC transformer that I need, with a 12V output and a female barrel jack connector matching the outer diameter. That, and Spehro's suggestion, is helpful - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't easily find an AC-AC adapter with a built-in female barrel jack like this one. Image from manufacturer's website:

[image]

You could find a suitably rated 120VAC:12VAC adapter and buy a female jack, and attach it, but I think when you're done replacing the pump + adapter will be more  economical.